# Citing mathoverflow answers using \bibitem(without using bibtex)

Tags: latex, bibliography

Is there a way to cite mathoverflow answers using the following :

```
\begin{thebibliography}

\bibitem ....the mathoverflow citation

\end{thebibliography}
```

I did the following :

```
\documentclass[11pt]{amsart}
\setlength{\textheight}{23cm}
\setlength{\textwidth}{16cm}
\setlength{\topmargin}{-0.8cm}
\setlength{\parskip}{0.3\baselineskip}
\hoffset=-1.4cm
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{amsmath,amscd,amssymb}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{conjecture}[subsection]{Conjecture}
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{proposition}[theorem]{Proposition}
\newtheorem{remark}[theorem]{Remark}
\numberwithin{equation}{section}
\newtheorem{definition}[theorem]{Definition}
\newtheorem{example}[theorem]{Example}
\newtheorem{corollary}[theorem]{Corollary}
\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\arabic{footnote}}
\input xy
\xyoption{all}

\begin{document}

some text \cite{MO1}
\begin{thebibliography}{1}

\bibitem{MO1} gowers (\url{https://mathoverflow.net/users/1459/gowers}), Examples of common false beliefs in mathematics, URL (version: 2020-09-03): \url{https://mathoverflow.net/q/23478}
\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

I know that there are ways to do it using bibtex and creating a separate .bib file. But I was thinking whether we could do it just using `\bibitem`?

Any help from anyone is welcome.

Comment: The code you show works fine for me. Can you specify what problem you have with it? https://i.stack.imgur.com/kbTeY.png

Answer (score 1):

You could copy the rendered citation from the top of the cite popup:

[image]

With some tiny modifications, like wrapping the urls into suitable macros, you can directly use this in your bibliography:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\begin{thebibliography}{1}
\bibitem{gowers} gowers (\url{https://mathoverflow.net/users/1459/gowers}), Examples of common false beliefs in mathematics, URL (version: 2020-09-03): \url{https://mathoverflow.net/q/23478}
\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @Sherlock Can you specify what is not working?

Comment: @Sherlock Did you test with the code from my answer with the correct spelling and syntax for `thebibliography`?

Comment: For  \documentclass[11pt]{amsart} it's not working

Comment: Please make a [mre]. Without it we can't know the peculiarities of your code and can only assume what works in normal document classes

Comment: @Sherlock I just tested, my answer works just the same with `amsart`

Comment: Yes I'm trying to do it .But I'm not finding where to write the codes

Comment: I have added now in my question.